# complex analysis, connected set,

Tags: general-topology

I am reading Conway text Function of one complex variable and going through the problem by myself, I get stuck on this one question though, 
the question asks

> If $ A  \subset X $ is connected, where $X$ is a metric space, and $ A \subset B \subset \text{closure}(A) $, then $B$ is connected.

the case where $A$ is closed is easy since $ A = \text{closure}(A)$.  But what about the case where $ A $ is open, though?

Can you guys give me some hint?

Thank you and have a nice day.

Comment: The crucial observation is that, since $B\subseteq \overline{A}$, every open set $U$ such that $U\cap B\ne\emptyset$ must satisfy $A\cap U\neq\emptyset$. Also, studying the special case in which $A$ is open may not be illuminating.

Comment: "Open" and "closed" are not cases.  Subsets of a metric space can be open, closed, both, or neither—and generally speaking, most are neither.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli ok, i got how to prove this now, so by contradiction, we can assume that $B$ is not connected that is $B = B_1 \cup B_2 $ where $B_1$ and $B_2$ are disjoint nonempty open set in $B$.  so then $ A \cap B_1$ and $ A \cap B_2 $ are nonempty by what you just said and they are also open in A and disjoint, and it is easily seen that $ A = (A \cap B_1) \cup (A \cap B_2) $ so then $ A$ is not connected, which is contradiction.  is this correct reasoning?? thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly unorthodox proof which I find highly intuitive. First, some concepts. A scale on a metric space $X$ is any function $R\colon X\to (0,\infty)$. Given a scale, a step is a pair of points $(x,y)$ such that either $d(x,y)<R(x)$ or $d(y,x)<R(y)$. Given a scale, a walk is a finite choice of points $x_1,\ldots, x_n$ such that each $(x_k,x_{k+1})$ is a step. Then, a metric space is connected if, and only if, given any scale $R$ on it, and any two points $x,y$ in it, there exists a walk whose end points are $x,y$. The proof is not hard.

Another useful fact is that in a metric space a subset $C$ is closed if, and only if, $d(C,x)=0$ implies $x\in C$, where $d(C,x)$ is the set-to-point distance, given as the infimum over $d(c,x)$ as $c$ ranges over $C$. The closure of a subset $S$ of $X$ is then precisely the set of all points $x\in X$ with $d(C,x)=0$.

So now, if $A\subseteq B\subseteq cl(A)$ and $A$ is connected, then to show $B$ is connected take a scale $R$ on $B$ and two points $x,y$ in $B$. These two points are at distance $0$ from $A$ so you can find points $x_A,y_A$ such that $d(x,x_A)<R(x)$ and $d(y,y_A)<R(y)$. Now since $A$ is connected, there is a walk connecting $x_A$ and $y_A$. Augmenting this walk with the step $(x,x_A)$ at the start and with $(y_A,y)$ at the end yields a walk connecting $x$ and $y$.

The nice thing with this proof is that, once one gets used to these simple concepts, both the claim and the proof become obvious: adding points that are arbitrarily close to points in a connected set can not harm connectedness.